# Selecting dataframe columns and updating names dynamically in R

Tags: r, function

I am writing a function taking bool arguments:

```
Discretize <- function(Data, Price, Hour) # Bool input
{
  num_var <- sum(Price, Hour)
  Data_Qual <- as.data.frame(array(0, dim = c(nrow(Data), num_var)))
  names(Data_Qual) <- c(ifelse(Price, "Price.Qual", numeric(0)),
                      ifelse(Hour, "Hour.Qual", numeric(0)))
}
```

but when I run the function: `Discretize(Data = Date, Price = T, Hour = F)`, I got the following error:

> Error in names(Data_Qual) <- c(ifelse(Price, "Price.Qual",
>   numeric(0)),  :    'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as
>   the vector [1]

Could anyone help me with this problem, thanks!

Comment: There's some information missing here. What is `Data_New` and `Date`? Also, your call should contain `Data=Date`, but that's probably a typo. Also, what do you want to change with `names`? It's easier to understand if you use `colnames` or `rownames`, but from your error the number of columns is not 2 like the number of names you defined.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, and Data_New should be Data, the input argument. What I am trying to do here is to give names to the data.frame :Data_Qual based on the input variables, which take bool values. So when I call  Discretize(Date=Date,Price=T,Hour=F), I am expecting the data.frame to have only one colum, the Price, but I got the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your function less complicated, and working, like this:

```
Discretize <- function(Data, Price, Hour) {
  df <- Data[,c(Price, Hour)]  
  names(df) <- c("Price.Qual", "Hour.Qual")[c(Price, Hour)]
  df
}

sampleData <- data.frame(P=1, H=2)
Discretize(Data=sampleData,Price=TRUE,Hour=FALSE)

#Price.Qual 
#     1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this really help! Just for curiosity, I really wondering what's the problem with my code

Comment: Well, besides some unecessary steps, the key mistake was using `ifelse` inside the names call. When evaluated to false, `numeric(0)` still ocuppies one space in the vector, so you always had two names for your dataframe, but you can't give two names to a dataframe with one column. To do that, you'd have to use something like `NA` instead of `numeric(0)` and then `names <- names[!is.na(names)]` to remove the names which were given the `NA` value.